# How does Node.js handle big arrays and objects included multiple times using require()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

In my project I indirectly use some big arrays of data - in my specific case these are Minecraft block and item info.

As I said I'm using the data indirectly - one of my dependencies uses it. But now I want to use it too which means I'll need to `require()` that `.js` file that contains all the data. Since there are no constants in javascript and the loaded object will be mutable my question is if it will really be loaded two times in Node's memory. If it is, what can I do to save memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require the same file twice it only gets loading into memory once, you just get two references to it. The data will usually be mutable as well, so if one place modifies it the other place *will* see that change (which can lead to some confusing bugs!). You can avoid that either by using immutable data structures (like those in immutable.js) or by using Object.freeze (but be aware that this just does shallow immutability, so if any of the keys of your object are themselves mutable objects they will remain so).

Answer (score 2):

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

So if your dependency is inside your project, and it `require`s the same *file* that you want to `require` - it will return the same object. But if your dependency A is a node module that requires dependency B (the big array) as a separate node module... And you add B as a dependency for your whole project, it will resolve to a different file. That means it will be a different object.

> Modules are cached based on their resolved filename. Since modules may resolve to a different filename based on the location of the calling module (loading from node_modules folders), it is not a guarantee that require('foo') will always return the exact same object, if it would resolve to different files.